# C# How can i use a string value in a another method

Tags: c#

How can i use the value from ip and user (line 3) in line 12?

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(string ip, string user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Content = "Connected to: " + user + " " + "(" + ip + ")";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(user);
    }
}
```

The code from the other Form:

```cs
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow w1 = new MainWindow(txtip.Text,txtuser.Text);
        w1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm new to C #, thanks for your answers!

Comment: What is line 12? Can you please a comment in the code where you want to use it?

Comment: Neither `ip` or `user` is directly accessibly outside `MainWindow` without storing it somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _user;

    public MainWindow(string ip, string user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _user = user;
        label1.Content = $"Connected to: {_user} ({ip})";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_user);
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea why you got down-voted.  It's not clear from the question exactly what the OP meant (like why he shows two classes where it seems that he's only interested in the first one).  But, if you count the lines, your answer is pretty close to what one interpretation of the question might mean.  I upvoted you since someone else dinged you.